# How do I check if one string has all elements of the other string at least once

Tags: javascript

I’m quite new to programming, just learning JavaScript. 
Here is what I tried but it actually checks the length of the string and not if the elements in input match elements in alphabet. I’m trying to work around the includes command:

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 
        'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];  
var input = prompt("Type in a message","");  
for ( i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {  
    if(input.includes(alphabet[i])) {  
         alert("Bingo");  
    } else {   
         alert("Bollocks!");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly in fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8gLb6s7v/

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I see with your code, is that you will fire a alert for every letter in the alphabet array. In this code, you have a hit variable, set to false, which will be set to true if it results in a success.

My method uses the `indexOf`, which checks if the input has any letter of the current pointed letter in alphabet array. If so, it returns the actual index of it. If none, it returns -1:

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];  

var input = prompt("Type in a message","");  
var hit = false;

for( var letter in alphabet ){
    if( input.indexOf(alphabet[letter]) !== -1 ){
        hit = true;
    }
}

if( hit ){ alert( "Bingo" ); }
else { alert( "Bollocks!" ); }
```

Be aware that the code is case sensitive. So M will not match anything. You can work around this by using to `toLowerCase` method

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you mean. Look at this fiddle. I think this is what you mean. I have added a variable bingo and show the Bollock alert at the end.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8rbaLjp/)

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 
'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 
'z'];
var input = prompt("Type in a message", "");
var bingo = false
for (i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    if (input == (alphabet[i])) {
        bingo = true
        alert("Bingo");
}
}
if (bingo == false) {
     alert("Bollok")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing are you trying to check if something you input matches the small letter of English alphabet or what?

But usually regex is a good approach:

- Step 1 - build a regex of what you need to match
- Step 2 - check if something else matches

If You need to check every character in input is a small letter of English alphabet

```
var input = "aahahahaaa"; // try with "nope,nomatch!"
var regex = new RegExp("[a-z]" + "{" +  input.length + "}");
console.log(regex);
if (input.match(regex) !== null) console.log("YUP CHAMP")
else console.log("NOPE BLOKE")
```

If you need to match other characters, simply modify the regex. I can't cover all the cases but here are some for you to test out:

For small and capital letters:

```
 var regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]" + "{" +  input.length + "}");
```

For above and spaces

```
var regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z\s]" + "{" +  input.length + "}");
```

For above and numbers

```
var regex = new RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z\s]" + "{" +  input.length + "}");
```

Fast, clean, can handle very complex matching rules. 
This is how the pros do it ;)

Here is the: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dqfn87o/4/)

And here is a good tutorial about Regular expressions:
[regexone](https://regexone.com/)

And a playground for you to test regexes as you learn:
[playground](https://regexr.com/)

Welcome to the wonderful world of regexes :)